# How to do code-review/debug/coding/test/version-control for C++ on perforce and VMS

Tags: c++, python, linux, perforce, vms

I am working on C++ programming with perforce (a version control tool) on VMS.

I need to handle tens or even hundreds of C++ files (managed by perforce) on VMS.

I am familiar with Linux, python but not DCL (a script language) on VMS.

I need to find a way to make programming/debug/code-review as easy as possible.

I prefer using python and kscope (a kde based file search/code-review GUI tool that can generate call graph) or similar tools on VMS.

I do not have sys-adm authorization, so I prefer some code-review GUI tools that can be installed without the  authorization.

Would you please give me some suggestions about how to do code-review/debug/programing/compile/test by python on VMS meanwhile using kscope or similar large-scale files management tools for code-review ?

Any help will really be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you could compile a port of emacs and a port of some version controller on your VMS system. But I would ask such questions on VMS specific lists or forums.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is pretty broad so it's tough to give a specific answer.

It sounds like you have big goals in mind which is good, but since you are on VMS, you won't have a whole lot of tools at your disposal.  It's unlikely that kscope works on VMS.  Correct  me if I'm wrong.  I believe a semi-recent version of python is functional there.

I would recommend starting off with the basics.  Get a basic build system working that let's you build in release and debug.  Consider starting with either MMS (an HP provided make like tool) or GNU make.  You should also spend some time making sure that your VMS based Perforce client is working too.  There are some quirks that may or may not have been fixed by the nice folks at Perforce.

If you have more specific issues in setting up GNU make (on VMS) or dealing with the Perforce client on VMS, do ask, but I'd recommend creating separate questions for those.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it's not clear from your question what sort of programming you want to do on VMS: C++ or python??

Assuming your first goal is to get familiar with the code-base, i.e. you want the ease of cross-ref'ing the sources:

- If you have Perforce server running on VMS, then you may try to connect to it directly with **Linux Perforce client**. And do "review" locally on Linux.
- If you've **no Linux client**, I'd try fetching the latest revisions off and importing raw files it into an external repository (svn, git, fossil etc.). Then again using Linux client and tools.

If your ultimate goal is to do all development off VMS, then it may not really be viable -- the code may use VMS specific includes, system/RMS calls, data structs. And sync'ing the changes back and forth to VMS *will* get messy.

From my experience, once you're familiar with the code-base, it's a lot more effective to make the code-changes directly on VMS using whatever editor is available (EDIT/TPU, EDT, LSE, emacs or vim ports etc.).

As for debugging - VMS native debugger supports X-GUI as well as command-line. Check your build system for debug build, or use `/NOOPT /DEBUG` compile and `/DEBUG` link qualifiers.

BTW, have a look into DECset, if installed on your VMS system.